# Completar un campo en una pagina web al hacer click en un Boton de mi extencion

Tags: javascript, html, json

Sepan disculpar las molestias, pero ando con el siguiente inconveniente....

Estoy intentanto hacer una extencion en Chrome que tiene varios botones.. la idea es que al darle click en el boton de la extencion. me complete un campo en mi formulario. Quizas es media naba la pregunta pero no logro encontrar una manera de que el completar los campos se ejecute solo cuando presionan en el boto espesifico...

[No tengo mucha idea la verdad he seguido varios videos de internet y no logro dar con el resultado que necesito.] si alguien es tan amable de explicarme se agradeceria mucho!!.

Saludos-

Les comparto lo que tengo:

1)manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "PRUEBA 1",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Una extensión para autocompletar.",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js","capturar_texto.js","popup.js","login_usuarios.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

//

2)login_usuario.js: en esta parte el codigo que esta comentado es el que necesito que se ejecute.. lo que no entiendo es :

a) estoy escuchando bien el boton?? ( me refiero a que si la sintaxis es correcta, y verdaderamente, cuando de click sobre el boton que esta en el  apartado (3) ('btn1') se ejecutaria lo que deje comentado...

```
 document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function() {



//document.querySelector("input[name="usuario"]").value="hola";


});
```

3)popup.html (este es el que muestra los botones de la extencio):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Menú Desplegable</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Menú</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <button class="b" id= "btn1" name="h" >Op 1</button>

          <!--  <button class="b" id= "btn1" name="h" onclick="prueba()" >Op 1</button>-->

            <button class="b" id= "btn2"  >Op 2</button>
            <button class="b" id= "btn3" >Op 3</button>
            <button class="b" id= "btn4" >Op 4</button><!-- Login_usuarios -->
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="content.js"></script>
<script src="login_usuarios.js"></script>
<script src="capturar_texto.js"></script>
</html>
```

////

[el resto de los .js tambien completan formularios pero de otras paginas, se me ocurrio separarlos.. (tampoco funcionan)]

Espero me puedan ayudar. GRACIASS!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que veo en tu código HTML no tienes algún input, mucho menos uno nombrado "usuario".

Podrías probar usando la misma sintaxis que usaste con el botón, creas un input en el HTML y le defines un id, ese id lo llamas dentro de la función que declaras después de pasar el evento "click".

```
document.getElemntById('aquí va el id del input').value = "el valor que quieras";
```

Ahora, si quieres crear el input del formulario luego de dar click en el botón, puedes probar el método createElement().
Que funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
let input = document.createElement('input');
input.id = "inputPrueba";
```

De esta forma lo creas y le asignas un id.

Espero haberte ayudado con tu problema, saludos.

Comment: Buenas tardes Cristian, gracias por responder. el  input  con name="usuario" esta en la pagina web que se tiene que completar . el HTML " 3)popup.html" es el menu de mi extencion. Se supone que al darle click en el boton OP1 de mi extencion deberia llamar a "2)login_usuario.js" que esta escuchando con el eventlistener y completa el campo de la pagina web con "hola" [Que es lo que esta comentado en "2)login_usuario.js" ]

Comment: Se supone que "2)login_usuario.js" esta eschando si en la pagina web que estoy hay un "input[name="usuario"]" y le va a asignar el valor "hola" con [value="hola" ]. pero esto solo se tiene que activar si le doy click a mi boton desde mi extencion